# Call another function with controls video (HTML, JS)

Tags: javascript, html, video, controls

I have a question,is it possible to call a javascript function with the play button from the video tag controls ?

```
<video controls id="video" src="../../data/myvideo.mp4"></video>
```

I don't know and I didn't find how to have acces in JS to the play button from the "controls".

I tried getElement or query but nothing works.

Comment: you could add an onplay event listener to the video object and use that to trigger your code?

Comment: It's a possibility but I was hoping to have direct acces to the button like "play" or the "time bar".

Answer (score 0):

video tag has onplay attribute you can give custom func.this attribute. Also you can see all different video tag attribute with console.log getElementById("yourTagId")